# What is wrong with this code?? It is giving output as 0.0000?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>     
double sum_1(int n)    
{
    int i=1;    
    double s;    
    while(n>0)    
    {
        s=s+i/(2*i+2);    
        i=i+2;
        n--;
    }    
    return s;
}

int main()    
{
    int n=5;    
    double s1;    
    printf("Enter n:\n");    
    scanf("%d",&n);    
    s1= sum_1(n);    
    printf("sum = %lf",s1);    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: uninitialized variable `s` in `sum_1()`

Comment: In `s=s+i/(2*i+2);` the second half is evaluated first. `i/(2*i+2)` is done using integer division which results in 0. Change it to `s=s+i/(2.0*i+2);`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what is wrong with the output. What do you expect instead and what input did you provide?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
 s=s+i/(2*i+2);
```

in the first iteration, `s` is used uninitialized. Since this is a type which can have trap representation, and it's address is never taken, trying to use the uninitialized value here invokes undefined behavior.

That said, the grouping of the statement

```
s=s+i/(2*i+2);
```

is same as

```
s = s + ( i / (2*i+2) );
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- integer division
```

so, it involves integer division, which is most likely what you don't want. You need to enforce floating point arithmetic, like

```
s=s+i/(float)(2*i+2);
```

Finally, for printing a `double`, `%f` is sufficient, `%lf` is not needed and has no effect.

Comment: No, just say no to `float` please.

Comment: Whether a type has a trap representation is irrelevant to the fact that using an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration whose address is not taken has behavior not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2.